# Moving text if input is focused or if input contains any text

Tags: css

I want to move my text only if input is focused, and stay there if input contains any value.

I tried `:empty` but this moves text after page reload so my text moves even without focusing on input.

Here is my css code that moves text:

```css
.wrapper input:focus ~ label {
    top: -12px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `valid` pseudo, so when there's text inside the input it'll move your label:

```
.wrapper label {
    position: relative;
}

.wrapper input:focus ~ label,
.wrapper input:valid ~ label {
    top: -12px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f62kvsnb/

Comment: Thanks it helped but i don't know why it haven't worked before because i tried it

Answer (score 0):

Change your pixel point from negative to positive points, if it not change, change your point scale from pixel to percentage.

```
.wrapper input:focus ~ label {
    top: 12px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need the css still works even if the input value is invalid (e.g. on `<input type="email">`):

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="email" placeholder=" " required>
  <label>text</label>
</div>
```

```css
.wrapper label {
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper input:focus ~ label,
.wrapper input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ label {
  top: -12px;
}
```

caveat, this requires the `placeholder` attribute to be present, even if it's just a blank space.

demo: https://codepen.io/widyakumara/pen/pozBPWv